# TabSheet does not display images

Tags: delphi, tabs, vcl

Is there any reason why images are not being displayed if I place it into tabsheet? Just shows white background instead.

Comment: Which Delphi version and what kind of an image? 2006 shows images on tabsheets? Have you tried to show the image without the tabsheet?

Comment: 7

Iamge shows up fine when not using tab sheets. It's being displayed however, if I set parent

Comment: Yes parent (and owner must be set). But these are set automatically if you are using the form designer. Without a parent a component does not know where it must be painted.

Comment: `Owner` does not need to be set for a component to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a possibly similar problem with images not showing (some time ago) and I fixed it by adding a panel and then image. (I don't really get the difference, but it worked then)

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating them at run-time, be sure to set their Parent property. The parent is responsible for providing the painting context.
No parent = nothing displayed.

Answer (score 0):

What type of images (bmp or jpeg)? Include jpeg unit in your code if you use jpg's.

Comment: What component do you use to display png and gif?